# What title does a queen's husband get while she's sitting on the Iron Throne?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Cersei is the queen and she sits on the Iron Throne, as ruler. If she tries to marry a man, let's take Euron as an example, will Euron get the title of "King" or will he just be treated as "husband to the queen"?

If yes, what is the extent of his powers? Is it just the same level as to what Cersei had when she was still Robert's wife?

Comment: Interesting question. Prince Phillip is titled Prince, although he's the husband to the Queen. My knowledge of monarchies is dreadful so I can't tell you of any other counter or supporting examples, but given ASOIAF is said to be "based on" the War of the Roses, this might be what GRRM/D&D had in mind. Just one question, which possibility is "yes" in your final paragraph?

Comment: @Edlothiad if the husband gets the title of prince consort, then in GOT, the kingdom remains with a queen as its ruler but there will never be king? Unless a rebel takes place. Though Cersei only had limited powers when she was still Robert's husband, it's unclear whether a husband to the queen (who sits on the iron throne) gets more power than a king-sitting-on-the-iron-throne's wife.

Comment: An example from Tudor times (shortly after the wars of the roses): Queen Mary I of England was married to Phillip, Prince of Asturias (later King Phillip II of spain).  There was an act of parliament setting out his titles, honours and rights that granted him the title King, and authority as co-regent.

Comment: Are you looking to know where the power lies or what they'd be called.

Comment: Well, I wouldn’t say “never”; unless she changes the laws of succession their first male child will still inherit the throne. Though when the Targs were in power there was a conclave in 110 AC that said ALL males in the line had to die before a female had a shot, so Cersei keeping the throne without being Queen Regent would already be a departure from that, and I could see her giving equal rights to female offspring.

Comment: I imagine that Euron's influence would be roughly on par with Cersei's during Robert's reign. Cersei was a Lannister, and therefore had her father's power behind her; Euron is a Greyjoy (and a king already, no less), and therefore has the power of the Iron Fleet behind him. But since he himself is not the Lord Protector of the Realm and Ruler of the Seven Kingdoms, he would take a backseat to the Queen.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet Cersei didn't enjoy any extraordinary powers while Robert lived though. Lannister Power did not help her to escape domestic violence, rapes or just getting whatever she wanted either (Robert would sometimes give in to her "demands" if he wasn't in the mode for a fight). Lannister guards unit Tywin sent with her never helped her with that.

Comment: Another example from English history: Queen Victoria wanted to grant her husband Albert the title King-Consort, but Parliament refused to bestow that title on a foreigner. He did not live long enough to give them an opportunity to reconsider. (Prince Phillip is likewise foreign-born, and also less popular in Britain than Albert was.) So, he became Prince Consort instead. In English history, the title of King-Consort has been used by husbands of the ruling Queen who also had their own kingdom, such as Phillip II.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## King Consort

would be the title of a man who married a ruling Queen. Although it's unclear what powers they would have in Westeros, parts of the texts suggest that it would be the Queen who ruled and the King Consort would be simply that, a consort. We can look at the first Queen of Westeros, Rhaenyra, to explore the outcome.

> Long before any man had reason to doubt her innocence, the question of selecting a suitable consort for Rhaenyra had been of concern to King Viserys and his council. Great lords and dashing knights fluttered around her like moths around a flame, vying for her favor.
>   <sub>Princess and the Queen</sub>

> One of the chief pillars of support for Rhaenyra’s claim was her consort, yet Prince Daemon represented one of her greatest weaknesses as well. The prince had made more foes than friends during the course of his adventures.
>   <sub>ibid.</sub>

However, this seemed to depend on the person who would end up being Consort to the Queen. In Westeros, Queen Rhaenyra first looked at lords and dashing knights looking for her favour. In such a case, it is likely that Rhaenyra would rule with all the power, and the consort would behave as an ordinary Queen Consort did. However, given she she married the former King's brother, her uncle, Daemon, people feared he would take control.

> "Make no mistake, **should Rhaenyra ever sit the Iron Throne, it will be Daemon who rules us, a king consort** as cruel and unforgiving as Maegor ever was. My own head will be the first cut off, I do not doubt, but your queen, my daughter, will soon follow.”
>   <sub>Princess and the Queen</sub>

However, he is still titled consort, suggesting that he is still titled as the spouse of the monarch despite having taken power.

Taking another example into account, Daenerys upon her return to Westeros and Prince Quentyn's plans of becoming her consort (before he gets fried).

> A hundred years ago, Daenerys Targaryen came to Dorne to make a peace. Now another comes to make a war, and my brother will be her king and consort. King Quentyn. Why did that sound so silly?
>   <sub>The Winds of Winter - Arianne I</sub>

While this gives us no details about how much power Quentyn would have, it reaffirms his role as consort.

In Meereen, on the other hand, the Queen seems to be in power, and on her departure the consort takes rule.

> Daenerys, my queen, I will gladly wash you from head to heel if that is what I must do to be your king and consort."
>   <sub>A Dance with Dragons - Daenerys VI</sub>

> "Your Grace, I do not like this halt. This may be some trap. The Sons of the Harpy—"
>   "—have been tamed," declared Hizdahr zo Loraq. "Why should they seek to harm my queen when **she has taken me for her king and consort? Now help that man, as my sweet queen has commanded.**" He took Dany by the hand and smiled.
>   <sub>ibid.</sub>

The above two passages suggest that the queen is in charge, albeit we see how that changes upon Daenerys' departure below.

> Hizdahr zo Loraq might be his queen's consort, but he would never be his king. "If His Grace wishes for me to remove myself from court …"
>   "His Radiance," the seneschal corrected. "No, no, no, you misunderstand me. His Worship is to receive a delegation from the Yunkai'i...
>   <sub>A Dance with Dragons - The Queensguard</sub>
>
> All kneel for His Magnificence Hizdahr zo Loraq, Fourteenth of That Noble Name, King of Meereen, Scion of Ghis, Octarch of the Old Empire, Master of the Skahazadhan, Consort to Dragons and Blood of the Harpy,"
>    <sub>ibid.</sub>

Note that even by his own herald, he is titled Consort to Daenerys.

And now, finally, we can look at Nymeria and her consorts, which were merely counsellors and nothing more.

> Though she married twice more (first to the aged Lord Uller of Hellholt, and later to the dashing Ser Davos Dayne of Starfall, the Sword of the Morning), Nymeria herself remained the unquestioned ruler of Dorne for almost twentyseven years, her husbands serving only as counselors and consorts.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire - Ancient History: Ten Thousand Ships</sub>

In conclusion, it is rather unclear as to what powers a consort would have, but in all cases they are second to the Queen; they can however, depending on their "worth" or "rank", rule over the queen.

Comment: Turns out they use "Prince Consort" when this happens in real life.

Comment: Note that in most of those quotes, "king" and "consort" are separate terms _and_ lower case, so it's not 100% clear that it's an actual title with any meaning in Westeros Law. The word "consort" (lower case) is a generic term for any spouse of a reigning monarch, regardless of their other titles.

Answer (score 12):

#### Official Titles and Precedent

Other than what Edlothiad's mentioned, official titles of the person who sits the Iron Throne are:

> King/Queen of the Andals and the Rhoynar and the First Men, Lord/Lady of the Seven Kingdom, Protector of the Realm.

By precedent, when Rhaenyra Targaryen became Queen, her husband, Prince Daemon Targaryen chose the title "Protector of the Realm" for himself. The other titles belonged to Rhaenyra.

> Three hundred sets of eyes looked on as **Prince Daemon Targaryen placed the Old King’s crown on the head of his wife**, proclaiming her Rhaenyra of House Targaryen, First of Her Name, Queen of the Andals, the Rhoynar, and the First Men. **The prince claimed for himself the style Protector of the Realm**, and Rhaenyra named her eldest son, Jacaerys, the Prince of Dragonstone and heir to the Iron Throne.
> <sub>The Princess and the Queen</sub>

Do note that Queen Consorts have never claimed that title for themselves during the reigns of their husbands. This is however just about the official title. As Edlothiad says, the alternate styles would be "King Consort" or "King" or "Your Grace".

But it must also be noted that Daemon is not the only one who claimed that title. When Aegon II fell into coma after his fight against Princess Rhaenys (Queen who never was), his brother Prince Aemond claimed that title as well when he became Prince Regent. He was as you can guess, not married to his brother.

> “You must rule the realm now, until your brother is strong enough to take the crown again,” the King’s Hand told Prince Aemond. Nor did Ser Criston need to say it twice. And so one-eyed Aemond the Kinslayer took up the iron-and-ruby crown of Aegon the Conquerer. “It looks better on me than it ever did on him,” the prince proclaimed. **Yet Aemond did not assume the style of king, but named himself only Protector of the Realm** and Prince Regent. Ser Criston Cole remained Hand of the King.
> <sub>The Princess and the Queen</sub>

Cersei Lannister also assumed the title '*Protector of the Realm*' during Joffrey and (presumably) Tommen's minority while serving as Queen Regent like Aemond did during his term as Prince Regent:

> A herald's voice rang out. "All hail His Grace, Joffrey of the Houses
> Baratheon and Lannister, the First of his Name, King of the Andals,
> the Rhoynar, and the First Men, and Lord of the Seven Kingdoms. All
> hail his lady mother, **Cersei of House Lannister, Queen Regent, Light
> of the West, and Protector of the Realm**."
> <sub>AGOT - Sansa V</sub>

#### Powers of the Consort

It is unclear what powers would the Consort hold. Most Consorts have never interfered in governance of the realm, which is performed by the King/Queen-Regnant and his/her councillors. Some have a certain degree of influence at court like Cersei or Alicent Hightower. Some actually advise and help their husbands like Queen Alysanne. So it would most certainly depend on the Consort and their Regnant Spouse to determine how much influence and power would the Consort wield.

Furthermore, there has never been a Queen-Regnant on the Iron Throne except Rhaenyra. Her husband Daemon however seems to have exercised only Military powers (Much like his nephew Aemond but he also happened to be Prince regent so he could administer the realm as well unlike Daemon), which can be attributed to the fact that Rhaenyra's brief reign started and ended in war. But he did not have any power to override Rhaenyra's commands any more than Cersei had any power to overturn or override Robert's edicts. Rhaenyra had ordered the Lord of Maidenpool to kill Daemon's alleged paramour. Daemon did not indicate at all that he had the power to overrule Rhaenyra nor did Lord Manfryd Mooton suggest anything like that.

Remember there's a difference between a Monarch and their consorts. The Crown and the Powers belong to the Monarch, their consorts may wear a Crown but they have no ruling powers.